# Javascript / Node JS - using regex to transform a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

In my `nodeJs` code I make a REST call to a 3rd party api and one of the values in the response is a string value e.g:

```
  "total": "-15"
```

Note that this value can either be a negative number, zero or a positive number, but as a string.

e.g:

```
   "total": "-5"
   "total": "0"
   "total": "+3"
```

How can I convert this value to be as follows? Based off the above example:

```
   5 under
   level par
   3 over
```

I am quite new to `node/javascript` - is `regex` the best option to do this?

Comment: Regex might be the shortest line of code to solve this, but it's surely easier and more comprehensible to convert the string to a number, and write a little to test for == 0, < 0, >0 and output accordingly.

Comment: @BluntJackson can you please share an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Blunt Jackson said, regex will probably be slower. Here is a conversion function example:

```js
const toText = (value) => {
  const parsed = parseInt(value)
  return parsed  > 0 ? `${parsed} over` : parsed  < 0 ? `${Math.abs(parsed)} under` : 'level par';
}

console.log(toText("-5"));
console.log(toText("0"));
console.log(toText("+3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this question because I like Code Golf :D

So my suggestion would be this one-liner:

```js
const toText = v => v == 0 ? "level par" : v < 0 ? `${-v} under` : `${+v} over`;

console.log(toText("-5"));
console.log(toText("0"));
console.log(toText("+3"));
```

Works with Numbers or Strings as parameter.